NextJS app router dynamic routes not working with any named HTTP methods
This is the code placed inside /app/api/password/reset/confirm/[userId]/[idToken].ts.
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

// Define and export the GET handler
export const GET = async (request: NextRequest, context: { params: { userId: number; idToken: string } }) => {
  const { userId, idToken } = context.params;

  const userID : number = 1
  const IDToken : string = "c8jzmm-8e51a9981443975cf764d26ddb20093a"

  if (userId === userID && idToken === IDToken) {
    // Return a response if the token is valid
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Password reset link is valid', userId, idToken });
  } else {
    // Return an error response if the token is invalid
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Invalid password reset link' }, { status: 400 });
  }
};

This is what error message I getting if I'm doing a request from browser or from Terminal.
GET /api/password/reset/confirm/1/c8jzmm-8e51a9981443975cf764d26ddb20093a 405 in 17ms
 ⨯ No HTTP methods exported in '/home/code/Documents/playground/frontend/projects/signupwithallauth/app/api/password/reset/confirm/[userId]/[idToken].ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.

below is the http request made from terminal,
code@code:~$ http GET http://localhost:3000/api/password/reset/confirm/1/c8jzmm-8e51a9981443975cf764d26ddb20093a
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 15 Jun 2024 08:17:48 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
vary: RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch

If the dynamic routes working fine then, the route.ts file should return any response other than 405 Method Not Allowed.

You are missing the route.ts file, which is why you are getting the error. You should add a route.ts file and move your handler code to it.
The correct path will be:
/app/api/password/reset/confirm/[userId]/[idToken]/route.ts
Then run:
http GET http://localhost:3000/api/password/reset/confirm/1/c8jzmm-8e51a9981443975cf764d26ddb20093a

It should give you the following output:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 15 Jun 2024 08:52:59 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
content-type: application/json
vary: RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch

{
    "idToken": "c8jzmm-8e51a9981443975cf764d26ddb20093a",
    "message": "Password reset link is valid",
    "userId": "1"
}

By default, all params will be of type string. Remove the strict type check in the params check condition as follows:
  if (userId == userID && idToken === IDToken) {

Update the code to place it in the route.ts file:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

// Define and export the GET handler
export const GET = async (
  request: NextRequest,
  context: { params: { userId: number; idToken: string } }
) => {
  const { userId, idToken } = context.params;

  const userID: number = 1;
  const IDToken: string = "c8jzmm-8e51a9981443975cf764d26ddb20093a";

  if (userId == userID && idToken === IDToken) {
    // Return a response if the token is valid
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "Password reset link is valid",
      userId,
      idToken,
    });
  } else {
    // Return an error response if the token is invalid
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Invalid password reset link" },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }
};

Dynamic Route Segments
